# How to Convert <Object><param></param></Object> into String?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, object-tag

I am working in MVC CSHTML page and i want to convert the following code into string and want to assign that string in the parameter of

```
<object width="75" height="75" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="@Url.Content(playerpath)" name="fp_97432156_api" id="fp_97432156_api">
                                <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
                                <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
                                <param value="high" name="quality">
                                <param value="#000000" name="bgcolor">
                                <param value="opaque" name="wmode">
                                <param value="config={&quot;plugins&quot;:{&quot;controls&quot;:{&quot;volume&quot;:false}},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;fp_97432156&quot;,&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;@Url.Content(path)&quot;},&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;@Url.Content(path)&quot;}]}" name="flashvars">
                            </object>
```

How can i convert the following code into string where playerpath & path are dynamic values.

All answers are accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `runat="server"` to the `object` tag client side then you should be able to access it directly on the server, this would allow you to convert it to a HTML string e.g.

**Client**

```
<object id="myObjControl" runat="server">
...
</object>
```

**Server**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
    myObjControl.RenderControl(writer);
    var outputStr = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: As i am working in CSHTML Page i can't access myObjcontrol at server side. Any help please?

Comment: @AbhayAndhariya yes you can...with the introduction of Razor you no longer have codebehind pages with MVC, you just need to place the code in your CSHTML page but within a code block `<% ... %>`.